# can you guys create a tag for push notifications or any alternative tag available for this?

Tags: support, tags

can you guys create a tag for push notifications or any alternative tag available for this? i tried to create a question for push notification but does not find the tag push notification. can someone clarify which tag should i use for push notifications?

Comment: streaming-api, or is it not related to the api ?.

Comment: Which question?